# Setting Grid widths with Resize - Notification needed

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, column-width

I am trying to adjust proportionally Column Widths (30, 30, 50, 130, 130, 130 at start) with the Form Resize and this is working, kind of...

Problem 1: I'd like to get rid of the +50 but the Resize is called for every Pixel.

Problem 2: Would resolve Problem 1 if I can get a notification that the drag of the width has stopped and the Mouse released and the Form Width is stable.

Problem 3: I need help making it work for reducing the Form Width. My Math is not great.

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
  aPcntR : Real;
  aPcntI : Integer;
  anInc : Integer;
begin
  if aClientWidth < 1 then Exit;
  if aClientWidth = ClientWidth then Exit;
  if aClientWidth+50 > ClientWidth then Exit; // Only adjust after an increase of at least 50
  aPcntR:=(((aClientWidth-ClientWidth) / ClientWidth)*100.0);
  aPcntI:=Abs(Round(aPcntR));
  for i:=0 to dbgridItems.Columns.Count-1 do
  begin
    anInc:=dbgridItems.Columns[i].Width*aPcntI div 100;
    dbgridItems.Columns[i].Width:=dbgridItems.columns[i].Width+anInc;
  end;
  aClientWidth:=ClientWidth;
  aClientHeight:=ClientHeight;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a handler for the `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` message, and do your resizing there instead of using `OnResize`:

```
interface

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    // Other declarations by IDE
  private
    procedure WMExitSizeMove(var Msg: TMsg); message WM_EXITSIZEMOVE;
  // Other stuff
  end;
```

[WM_EXITSIZEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is sent once, after the resize or movement is completed and the user releases the mouse.